# Have rights disputes kept Skeeter out of the Muppet movies, including "The Muppets"?

Tags: muppets

"The Muppets" has been celebrated by hardcore Muppets fans for bringing back long forgotten characters in a big way (like [Uncle Deadly](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Uncle_Deadly) and [Scooter](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Scooter)). [Skeeter](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Skeeter), on the other hand, was left out again. Skeeter is Scooter's twin sister and has, so far, only appeared in animated form in [Muppet Babies](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Muppet_Babies). Since that show was on the air for 8 seasons, and another decade after that in syndication, one would think that Skeeter's popularity would eventually guarantee her a spot in a real Muppet movie. That has still yet to happen.

Why wasn't Skeeter in "The Muppets"? Since she was created for the cartoon, **are the rights to her character owned by some other company?** And if that's the case, how could Disney not afford to buy the rights back? They're Disney.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Since that show was on the air for 8 seasons, and another decade after that in syndication, one would think that Skeeter's popularity would guarantee her a spot in a real Muppet movie.

I think the number of people aware of the Muppet Show (1976) and the older Muppet Movies foreshadow those that know about Muppet Babies (1984). Since in Muppet Babies most of the characters were the babies (except for the occasional parent figure), the gender roles were unbalanced. Thus the addition of Skeeter.

Though this is not to say that this is the reason why Skeeter was left out. There were other Muppet movies before "the Muppets" where Skeeter was not previously included.

- The Muppet Movie (Uncle Deadly, Scooter)
- Muppets from Space (Uncle Deadly, Scooter)
- The Muppets Go Hollywood
- Muppet Treasure Island (Uncle Deadly, Scooter)
- The Muppets Take Manhattan  (Uncle Deadly, Scooter)
- The Muppets' Wizard of Oz (Scooter)

I could be missing some, the full listing including 1 hour long tv specials could be found on the [Muppets Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Muppets#Filmography).

I am just going with why Skeeter was included in the Muppet Babies but not the other way. So you will have to ask why Skeeter was not included in any movies from 1984 onwards.

---

In response to the rights, I think it is logical to believe that Disney owns the rights to all characters. Not taking up rights just for Skeeter does not make any sense.

I decided to do some digging on the forums, and I stumbled on to a thread that asked [Muppet writer Jim Lewis about placing Skeeter into family](http://www.muppetcentral.com/forum/threads/the-brand-new-ask-jim-lewis-thread.32836/page-9#post-640356) in 2008,

> No. Why? Not really sure, to be honest. It could work, but I still see
>   her as a Muppet Baby, a balance for Scooter (His Bookishness to her
>   tom boy-ishness). I guess if she could be developed into something
>   more, a force in her own right as an adult, it might work. But I'm not
>   convinced. Plus, I'm lazy which is why I'm going to stop thinking on
>   this too much before my head starts to hurt.

Also in a separate [Ask Jim session](http://muppetbalcony.blogspot.com/2008_03_01_archive.html)

> Ahh, Skeeter. I wasn't there for the creation of the "Muppet Babies"
>   animated series, but I suspect she was added to the show so there'd be
>   another (dare I say, more balanced than Baby Piggy) female character
>   on a show aimed at kids. We threw around various bizarre scenarios
>   about what happened to Skeeter after "Muppet Babies," but none of
>   these were ever confirmed. Frankly, I suggest contacting the Federal
>   Witness Protection Program for more info. Let us know what you find
>   out.

Comment: So... Skeeter was excluded from the 2011 movie because she's female?

Comment: No, I am going with Skeeter was excluded based on her previous exclusion from the Muppet Show and previous Muppet Movies. @Abby

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be accusatory, especially not at you (you didn't write the films!). It sounds like Skeeter was created because the Muppet Babies needed a female character. But I think the gender ratio in the rest of the films is equally imbalanced, so I'm not sure it makes much sense to continue leaving her out (if that was indeed the sole reason for including her).

Comment: Indeed, they did have a chance with Miss Piggy thinking of her and Kermit as kids to push Skeeter in http://youtu.be/npUdoua5JSs?t=52s in Muppets Take Manhattan @Abby

Comment: Well, the muppet movies *did* have Janice, generally speaking.  One could easily ask why she was excluded from Muppet Babies.

Comment: Janice was actually added to the cast of Muppet Babies for it's final season, in episodes that were mysteriously left out of the syndication rotation on Nickelodeon.

Answer (score -3):

Well she was athlethic so maybe she went her own way and trained for the Olympics or something like that.
I'm thinking that that did not work so since she knew she was in a scenes related to her big shot brother did not want to bring bad publiclicty to the rest of the gang.